# length property returns wrong size(bytes) for an image

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have a .png file in my resources folder.(actual size is 411 KB)
When I convert the uiimage to nsdata and try accessing length property, it gives me wrong value.

Code...

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];

NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)];
int imageSize   = imgData.length;
NSLog(@"Image size in KB is %d",imageSize/1024); //-------- returns 631 KB
```

Please let me know if there is any other property which helps..

---

So here is my requirement....
I want to know the size of the image I pick from uimagepicker. The exact size of the image when I see it in the finder and the size which gets returned to me after picking it from the library is totally different... Is there any other property which can be used instead of length?

Comment: 631 Kb is the amount of memory the imgData takes. This has no direct relation to the way the image is stored in the actual file. If you want to get the file size, use the filesystem.

Comment: @RobvanderVeer clearly data length and file size would have a "direct relation". In this case they should be exactly equal. That is, were the data being read directly from the file, which it is not. Hence the issue.

Comment: @matt3141 first i agree your answer is the right one. But the file is not just read into memory here, it is read and processed. Hence the relation to file storage is not 'direct'.

Comment: @RobvanderVeer Okay, we're on the same page. I will say, though, I'm confused how a JPEG could be significantly larger than a PNG.

Comment: @matt3141, the file is larger because the 2nd argument to `UIJPEGRepresentation` is 1.0; its the compression factor. 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html

Comment: @RobvanderVeer I understand that it's not compressed, but JPEG still has a much more compact binary representation. I think `<Y><Cb><Cr>`, vs. something like `<R R><G G><B B><A A>` (if I recall PNG is two bytes per color, JPEG is one)

Comment: @matt3141, that is quite over my head. but I am imagining that a compressed PNG file (the input file) is smaller than a JPG with 100% quality. You'd have to try though.

Answer (score 4):

You are converting a png to a jpeg, and so different file size should be expected.

If you wish to get the file-size of the original, png image, do the following.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"png"];
NSData *rawData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSLog(@"%d", rawData.length);
```

Comment: Why not just ask the file system how big the file is?

Comment: @HotLicks I had assumed the poster wanted more than just the file size, as otherwise he could simply write `int imageSize = 411000;` (considering that the bundle isn't writable)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
unsigned int len = [data length];
uint32_t little = (uint32_t)NSSwapHostIntToLittle(len);
NSData *byteData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&little length:4];
```

Comment: At least explain what it does.

Answer (score 0):

When you loaded the image you decompressed it.  When you created "imgData" the image did not get recompressed with the same algorithm.  There would be no reason to expect the two to have the same size.